# Is there a json-formatter (directive/component) for angular?

Tags: angular

I'm upgrading an app from AngularJS to Angular. In AngularJS I used https://github.com/mohsen1/json-formatter to get displayed a beautified json. Is there an alternative for angular?

Comment: as workaround <pre>{{something | json}}</pre>

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/6Cbs6pIPqGlXM0hmXF9n?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui It works like in my AngularJS-App, thanks. If you post it as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either use [json-formatter-js](https://github.com/mohsen1/json-formatter-js) package

```typescript
import JSONFormatter from 'json-formatter-js';

@Directive({
  selector: 'json-formatter'
})
export class JsonFormatterDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() json: any;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.json) {
      const formatter = new JSONFormatter(this.json);
      this.elRef.nativeElement.appendChild(formatter.render());
    }
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/KYsEAj1og45Z0mJ8FUK8?p=preview)**

or create the same component for angular2

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6Cbs6pIPqGlXM0hmXF9n?p=preview)**